# How can I move share permissions to a new partition that I've moved data to?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2012, migration, share

I've just installed a new Disk Enclosure, and it's been set up, RAID configured, and the new partition R: is now configured on the file server VM.

I used robocopy to migrate all of our data from E: (NAS) to R: (DskEnc) and it has successfully done this, and copied over all NTFS permissions and kept all the relevant time/data on files/folders.

The new R: does not have all the shares on it though. So all of our users are still pointing to the old E: (NAS) partition, but I need to get them to point at the new R:(DskEnc) partition.

Is there a way for me to easily just transfer over the share permission details to R: while removing them from E: ?

Preferably with minimal interruption for users and making sure the R: is up to date with any changes since I migrated last Sunday.

From the users machine perspective it would just look like \server\sharedfolder

Thanks for help,

Sever: Windows Server 2012 Standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure of the synchronisation of your 2 servers and because you have under windows2012, you can use DFS for the sharing and DFS-R for the replication of your two servers.

You could follow those simples steps for  that :
1/ install and activate DFS replication (DFS-R) between the servers. When you are sure the initial replication is finished, all your files will be synchronised, and your user can be on any server, yours files will be the same.

2/ with DFS, you can create sharing which point to the two servers, with a priority on the new R:.

3/ You can migrate the users gradually. The old users point again to the ancient server. And the migrated users point to the DFS.

4/ When you finish to migrate all yours users, you can stop the replication, and delete the ancient server from your DFS.

good luck !

### Edit from my comment :

If you want to save your share permissions and apply then to your new drive, you can work with the registry.

Your share permissions are stored in the registry in this key :

```
hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\lanmanserver\shares
```

So you can export this key, edit it and apply yours modifications.

When you are ready, you can plan a scheluded task which will run a last robocopy and import yours new keys the sunday. Like this, the next monday, you will have yours files up to date with corrects share and NTFS permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So it is actually just one VM server, which is our file server, but there are now 2 disk partitions visible on it, E: and R: . E: has it's VHDX stored on the old NAS, and R: now has it's VHDX stored on the new DiskEnclosure. so E: & R: are both just VM disks on the one server. Does this make a difference to your suggestion, or will that process still work?

Comment: ok ! my suggestion is not your answer. If you want to save your share permissions and apply then to your new drive, you can work with the registry. Your share permissions are stored in the registry in this key : hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\lanmanserver\shares. I complete my answer....

Comment: Excellent, I've just looked at the key and that all makes sense now. I'll sort that out this weekend, thank you very much.